# getting first preceding-sibling and applying templates

Tags: xslt

I've the below XML code

```
<root>
<title num="1/2"><content-style font-style="bold">Application</content-style> (O 1 r 2)</title>
<para><content-style font-style="bold">2.</content-style>—(1) Subject to paragraph (2), these Rules apply to all proceedings in-</para>
<para>(2) These Rules do not have effect in relation to proceedings in respect of which rules have been or may be made under any written law for the specific purpose of such proceedings or in relation to any criminal proceedings.</para>
<para>(3) Where prior to the coming into operation of these Rules, reference is made in any written law to any Rules of Court that reference shall be to these Rules.</para>
</root>
```

and the below XSLT

```
<xsl:template name="para" match="para">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./@align">
      <div class="para align-{@align}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </div>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::title[1]/@num[1]">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <div class="para">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </div>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

here when i'm trying to run this `<xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::title[1]/@num[1]">` is not working as expected. For the first `para` the templates should be applied directly and for the second and third paras, first there should be a `<div class="para">` and inside it the templates should be applied(the otherwise condition), but here in my case for all the paras `<xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::title[1]/@num[1]">` is getting satisfied and it is directly applying templates. please let me know where am i going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
<xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::title[1]/@num[1]">
```

with

```
<xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*[1][name()='title']/@num">
```

Answer (score 3):

The `preceding-sibling::*` axis matches all preceding siblings, not just the immediate sibling, so you'd first have to select the immediate sibling and then check whether it's a `title` element:

```
preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::title
```

I'd suggest using a more XSLT-ish approach and replace the nested `<xsl:choose>` with more specific templates:

```
<xsl:template match="para[@align]" priority="2">
  <div class="para align-{@align}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para[preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::title/@num]" priority="1">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para">
  <div class="para">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

If you insist on using `<xsl:choose>`, use just one:

```
<xsl:template match="para">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./@align">
      <div class="para align-{@align}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </div>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::title/@num">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <div class="para">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </div>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>    
</xsl:template>
```